# Access the Property file (application.yml) of the primary application from the sub module in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have a application with two submudule project included in it.

```
rootProject.name = 'fete-bird-product'
include 'product-migration'
include 'Data'
```

Primary application which is **fete-bird-product** has the application.yml file

```
spring:
  application:
    name: PRODUCT-SERVICE
  profiles:
    active: dev
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://127.0.1:27017/FeteBird-Product
app:
  db:
    migrations:
      enabled: true
server:
  port: 8083
```

[image]

From the Submodule project **product-migration** I want to access below property in the main class

```
data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://127.0.1:27017/FeteBird-Product
```

I tried something like this but didn't work

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:PRODUCT-SERVICE")
public class Configuration {
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private static String MongoUri;

    public static  String getMongoUri() {
        return MongoUri;
    }
}
```

How can we access the primary application property from submudule.

Comment: the Submodule project, product-migration, does it produces it's own spring boot executable jar? If so, does the submodule project also have it's own application.yml file?

Comment: No, the submodule project is a Gradle module it doesn't have any application.yml file. My question is about reading the application of primary project from submodule. It's okay if submodule has no application.yml file, that not my requirement.

Comment: In that case replace `@PropertySource(value = "classpath:PRODUCT-SERVICE")` with `@Component` (or any other spring bean annotation for that matter) and it'll work just fine (I am still presuming you are using this submodule in your main project as a gradle dependency). `@PropertySource` is needed ONLY if you are trying to use a custom source for binding properties which you are not in this case as far as I have understood based on provided information.

Comment: Yes that correct I am using this submodule in the main application as a dependency